# How to set focus to FieldManager in BlackBerry?

Tags: blackberry

How to draw focus to a `VerticalFieldManager` in BlackBerry.

I have tried this but not working.

```java
VerticalFieldManager vv=new VerticalFieldManager(Manager.focusFOCUSABLE);
```

Comment: `Manager.focusFOCUSABLE` - this may cause compilation error. By default `VerticalFieldManager` is focusable. But if you don't add any focusable `Field` in it, it will not gain focus. So if you want an empty `VerticalFieldManager` to be focusable, then add a `NullField` to it (something like `new NullField(NullField.Focusable)`).

Comment: for manager to be focusable atleast one item in the manager is required which is focusable. If you don't have any focusable field in your manager then you can get focus on manager by adding the nullfield in it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

this is the way to do it:

```
VerticalFieldManager vv=new VerticalFieldManager(FOCUSABLE) {
    protected void paintBackground(Graphics g) {
    int prevColor = g.getColor();
    int bgColor;

    if (isFocus()) {
        bgColor = Color.Blue;
    } else {
        bgColor = Color.White;
    }

    g.setColor(bgColor);
    g.fillRoundRect(0, 0, getPreferredWidth(), getPreferredHeight(), 0, 0);
    g.setColor(prevColor);
}
    public void onFocus(int direction) {
    super.onFocus(direction);
    this.invalidate();
}
public void onUnfocus() {
    super.onUnfocus();
    this.invalidate();
}
};
_focusAnchor = new NullField(FOCUSABLE);
add(_focusAnchor);
```

Answer (score 1):

You can try calling `Field.setFocus` on it, but since a manager is a container, I'm not sure you are going to see "the focus" over it.

If it doesn't work, you can try also overriding the `paint` method and draw your own custom focus when `isFocus` returns true.

Answer (score 0):

try this -

```
VerticalFieldManager vv=new VerticalFieldManager(FOCUSABLE);
```

then add items to the vv.